# Slider prestashop 1.7

Tags: slider, carousel, prestashop-1.7

I  have question how to display full width slider prestashop 1.7 on mobile phones. I can't find file where I could change this.If anybody can HELP PLEASE.

Regards,
Pat

Answer (score 1):

The Slider actually depends on your theme how you present the slider TPL file with CSS.

Basically, in default theme of 1.7 your slider will be under the "container" DIV, And the Container DIV has a maximum width value set from Bootstrap about 940px max.

You need to Hook your slider out of Container DIV within WRAP div which allows you to show within 100% width.

See below how the main Container limit your ma size within 940px [Slider div under container DIV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi9xf.png)

Here 940px is max width and 15px padding on both left and right.

If i just place the Slider Div out of Container then what happens? See below

[Slider DIV out from Container DIV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLHsE.jpg)

So all you need to fix it from your theme where you HOOK slider module. By default in any responsive theme, your slider will be 100% width. This is not your slider is 100% width, This is why because your outer DIV make the limit of that width.

Hope that help you to understand how you can solve your issue